# Send value 0 when checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with checkboxes as in below

```
          <div class="col-xs-5 drinkingLeft">
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='beer'>             
            <input type="checkbox" name="beer" id="beer"class="require-one col-xs-1" value="0"/>
            <label for="beer" class="col-xs-10">Beer
            </label>
          </div>
```

ANd in js I am doing the below

```
$('#beer').on('change', function () {
  this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
}).change();
```

What I want is that when the checkbox is checkbox, send the value 1 or else send value 0. If i do not have the hidden input field

```
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='beer'>
```

then it does send 1 for the field. However I want to also make sure that the value 0 is send when it is not checked. How to do that?

Comment: Tried your code in a fiddle. it works http://jsfiddle.net/4qerZ/

Comment: Just remove the checkbox name(now you got 2 input with name beer) and make the hidden input sync value with it(no name, no value submit)

Comment: @MarsOne What I want is that when the checkbox is checkbox, send the value 1 or else send value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as below

```
<div class="col-xs-5 drinkingLeft">
<input type="checkbox" name="beer" id="beer"class="require-one col-xs-1" value="0"/>
<input id='beerHidden'  type='hidden' value='0' name='beer'>   
<label for="beer" class="col-xs-10">Beer </label>
</div>


 $('#beer').on('change', function () {
this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
 }).change();

$("#submit").click(function () {
if(document.getElementById("beer").checked){
document.getElementById('beerHidden').disabled = true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You need to use seperate `id` and `name` for hidden value `id ="beerhidden"`.

```
  <div class="col-xs-5 drinkingLeft">
        <input type='hidden' value='0' id ="beerhidden" name='beerhidden'>             
        <input type="checkbox" name="beer" id="beer"class="require-one col-xs-1" value="0"/>
        <label for="beer" class="col-xs-10">Beer
        </label>
  </div>

    $('#beer').on('change', function () {
       $("#beerhidden").val(this.checked ? 1 : 0);
    });
```

Comment: How would the server know which one to take? The first one or the 2nd one? That depends from server to server/ backend to backend language right? PHP possibly takes the 2nd value whereas java takes the first. So your answer wont work for all situation.. probably. You should see only one . I neeeded to send only one!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the name="beer" from the checkbox
2. Give the hidden input a new id like checkbeer

> $('#checkbeer').on('change', function () {
>   $('#beer').val(this.checked ? 1 : 0); }).change();

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="col-xs-5 drinkingLeft">
       <input type='hidden' value='0' name='hidden'>             
       <input type="checkbox" name="beer" id="beer"class="require-one col-xs-1" value="0"/>
       <label for="beer" class="col-xs-10">Beer
       </label>
  </div>



 $('#beer').on('change', function () {
      $("#beerhidden").val($(this).prop( "checked" ));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need js for this. All you need to do is write hidden field AFTER checkbox and set value for checkbox to 1 :

```
<div class="col-xs-5 drinkingLeft">
   <input type="checkbox" name="beer" id="beer"class="require-one col-xs-1" value="1"/>
   <input type='hidden' value='0' name='beer'>             
   <label for="beer" class="col-xs-10">Beer
   </label>
</div>
```

Doing so : if checkbox is checked,it is posted : 1
If it is not, then hidden is posted : 0

FYI: This is how Microsoft ASP.Net MVC does

Comment: Thanks. But that send both the values

Comment: Actually, yes ! Then, it must depend on how server gets value. MVC Framework discards second value I guess...

Comment: Thanks your solution though. I was able to device up a solution based on all the answers here. Realized that the way to go is to put a hidden field and then disable when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    $(this).find("input:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        var hidden = $("<input/>").attr({
                type: "hidden",
                name: input.attr("name"),
                value: "0",
            });
        hidden.insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

When the form is submitted, this inserts a hidden input with the value `0` after each unchecked input.

[See the jsfiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/4cV5y/)